# using smartphones SOC or other components as microcontroller like arduino

Tags: microcontroller, soc

i have a smartphone which has stuck in boot loop,i was just wondering if i could use it's internal components like SOC to use it as microcontroller like "arduino".have anyone ever tried it?or possess any information about my thought?is it possible?

Comment: They have been used to manage amateur high altitude balloon telemetry.

Comment: Most phones have a recovery mode.  Check the internet for how to do a recovery boot for your phone.  You can do a factory reset from there.  It will delete all of your data - and most importantly - all of your programs.  One of your programs has a problem which causes the boot loop.  Deleting it eliminates the problem.  If your recovery mode has a file manager then you could try deleting programs one by one until the bootloop goes away.  I fixed my wife's phone last weekend after a Whatsapp update ended up in a boot loop.

Comment: raspberry pi is an example of a smartphone SOC made accessible to experimentors.

Comment: @Jasen, no, it is not.  The pi is a set top box SoC, not a phone one.   All of the fine-grained power management needed for a phone is missing.

Comment: @JRE i'm not able to boot into recovery mode also.  :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically possible, but infeasible and not recommended. Here's why.

1. Don't imagine for a minute that you're going to remove the SoC from the phone. It's attached rather permanently, and you wouldn't be able to fabricate a board to host it yourself anyway.
2. Because the SoC is installed in a phone, you have very little access to any GPIOs. If the phone has physical buttons or LEDs, you might be able to wire those as inputs or outputs, but that's much more limited than a general-purpose microcontroller. Then you run into…
3. Documentation. Or, more accurately, the lack of it. Most documentation for mobile phone SoCs is under NDA. You're unlikely to ever get access to it. Relatedly…
4. Most modern phones have a locked bootloader. You can't load your own OS without the vendor's signing key. If the device will boot to an OS, you might be able to load your code as a normal application, but…
5. Your phone is broken! How do you plan on loading software onto a phone that's stuck in a boot loop? For all you know, there may be a faulty component that would make it impossible to use for your own purposes anyway.

TL;DR: If you have to ask, the answer is "no".

Comment: Well, many phones can have the bootloader unlocked, and those running Linux-based operating systems like Android require the manufacturer to offer the kernel sources as part of the terms by which they obtain a license to use it in the first place.  But yes, first the boot loop needs to be solved.

Comment: thanks :) i was just wondering if i could do that,i'm not expert at computers,but i will try it someday to install an OS and use it as microcontroller but much more powerful than one.